# is there a way to avoid or improve re-rendering of contact list while searching for contacts in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, search, optimization, react-native-flatlist

I am working on a react-native contact app with realtime search functionality. I have a problem with the contact List re-rendering on every keypress. is there a way I can optimize the search function where I can avoid the unnecessary re-renders on contacts Flatlist. Thanks, in advance

here is my contact component:

```
const Contacts = () => {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({});
 
  useEffect(() => {...read contacts and then save it to contact and inMemoryContact state});

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => <RenderContacts item={item} />;

  const renderList = () => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        data={contact}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
  />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={Styles.textStyle}>All Contacts</Text>
      {renderList()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

here is my search component:

```
const SearchBar = ({ updateContactState }) => {
  const { inMemoryContact } = useSelector(state => state.contactReducer);

  const searchContacts = value => {
    const filteredContact = inMemoryContact.filter(contactToFilter => {
      const contactLowerCase = `${contactToFilter.firstName} ${contactToFilter.lastName}`.toLowerCase();
      const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase();
      return contactLowerCase.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
    });
    updateContactState(filteredContact);
  };

  return (
    <View style={Styles.SectionStyle}>
      <MaterialIcons style={Styles.iconStyle} name="search" size={28} />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Search Contact"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={content => {
          searchContacts(content);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

here is my renderContact component which keeps re-rendering:

```
const RenderContacts = ({ item }) => {
     return item.phoneNumbers.map(element => (
        <TouchableOpacity ...>
          ... list of contacts
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ));
     )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your Problem Statement

"contact List re-rendering on every keypress"

### Proposed Solution

Use `debounce` to delay the call. Here is a detailed [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) on what debounce does. `Debounce` will delay processing your input until a certain delay period. This will prevent the extra re-renders that can occur while a user is quickly typing in the search bar.

`debounce` function is readily available in most utils library including [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce).

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Use RenderContact as a function not JSX element
2. Bring it outside the scope of your main function

Let me know which one works for you.